# Error when compiling simple python program

Tags: python

This script won't compile. I wanted to made a simple 21-style game for practice but I get an error:

```
X@X:~/Desktop$ python 21.py File "21.py", 
line 18 
int(ptotal) = ptotal + newcard 
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

[Here's the code](http://pastebin.com/mfc64c2d). Can anyone please help me? I'm obviously a beginner and the code is pretty sloppy.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on pastebin (which might expire or be offline while somebody reads your question), Just paste the code here on StackOverflow!

Comment: which version of python are you using ? there is a drastic difference between python 2.x and python 3.x, which may explain the `SyntaxError`, even after applying the modifications given by Ned Batchelder...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you got this syntax:

```
int(cone) == random.randrange(1, 11)
```

I think you mean this:

```
cone = random.randrange(1, 11)
```

This is also an (interesting) invention:

```
while hit is not "No" or "no" or "n":
```

You'll need:

```
while hit not in ["No", "no", "n"]:
```

Comment: Thanks! I made the changes but I can't ask for another card the program halts, here's the new modified code: http://pastebin.com/m1346acd1

P.S. My strange syntax is due to me starting with C++, moving to Java, then jumping on boat Python yesterday. I've been trying to learn from random internet sources and sometimes they give out-of-date and/or incorrect information.

Comment: @John, don't post multiple questions within one question.  Your original question was answered successfully, so accept this one and open another -- posting your code in it, just as @Davide says -- that's how SO **works**, you know...!

Comment: Ah, all right. Sorry then. I didn't want to bloat the website with my stupid questions. Thanks.